# Странность библиотеки Java

Tags: java, library, core

При попытке объявить переменную типа Pattern для создания паттерна регулярки столкнулся с тем, что данный класс отсутствует в стандартной библиотеке Java [**java.util.regex**]
[image: Доступный импорт в java.util.regex]

Если посмотреть в дереве пакетов и классов в стандартной библиотеке Java прямо внутри структуры проекта, то в либе **rt** по данному пути класс присутствует.
[image: Наличие класса в библиотеке rt.jar]

Вот, что появляется при попытке объявить переменную.
[image: Попытка объявить переменную класса Pattern]

Что было сделано:

1. Рестарт IDEA
2. Invalidate cashes
3. Проверены и включены везде(В структуре проекта, в компиляторе...) одинаковые языки Java (версия **8**)

Есть ли какие либо способы это исправить? И если выход только переустановить JDK, то как это безопаснее сделать на Linux?

OS: GNU/Linux Ubuntu XFCE 18.04 LTS

Java: 1.8.0_201

Comment: Если вручную импортируете, то компилируется? Т.е. вопрос это только проблема с автодополнением в idea или именно, что компилятор его не видит?

Comment: Обратился уже в техподдержку.
Класс Pattern почему-то оказался в списке исключений для автодополнения.
"
Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.
Make sure it's not excluded at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from auto-import and completion.
"
Вот что мне ответила поддержка и второе решение подействовало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. Make
> sure it's not excluded at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor |
> General | Auto Import | Exclude from auto-import and completion.

Вот что мне ответила поддержка и **второе** решение подействовало.
Мой класс **Pattern** почему-то оказался в **списке исключений при автодополнении**.